# Transform SQL Server table based on calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 200 |
| A | 200 |
| A | 0 |
| B | 300 |
| B | 200 |
| C | 100 |

I would like to transform this table into the following table

With calculation: for each element of column1, SUM (column2) / count of (non-zero column2)

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | ((200+ 200 + 0) / 2) = 200 |
| B | ((300 + 200) / 2) = 250 |
| C | 100 / 1 = 100 |

The only thing I can think of is looping through distinct elements of `Column1` and run:

```
SELECT SUM(Column2) 
FROM Table 
WHERE Column1 = i / (SELECT COUNT(Column2) 
                     FROM Table 
                     WHERE Column1 = i AND Column2 <> 0)
```

and generate a table.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Use aggregation:

```sql
SELECT Column1,
       SUM(Column2) / COUNT(CASE WHEN Column2 <> 0 THEN 1 END) AS Column2
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Column1
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Column2 <> 0 THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: If all the olumn2 is 0 for any column1 value then it will fail with error "Divide by zero error encountered.".

Comment: My answer is valid assuming the OP expects that every group would always have at least one non zero value.  If not, the OP would have to clarify the expected behavior.

Comment: Neat. `COUNT(NULLIF(Column2, 0))` is shorter if a little more obfuscated. @KaziMohammadAliNur is right though (in his own answer) that you may as well remove those rows in the `WHERE` as it won't affect the final result. As in: `(x + 0) / 1` is the same as `x / 1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use where clause to remove rows with 0 in column2 then use aggregation to have your desired result. But it will remove those column1 values which have 0 in all columnd2.

But Query2 will return rows with zero values in column2 instead of removing the removing the row.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table testTable (Column1    varchar(50), Column2 int);
 insert into testTable values('A',  200);
 insert into testTable values('A',  200);
 insert into testTable values('A',  0);
 insert into testTable values('B',  300);
 insert into testTable values('B',  200);
 insert into testTable values('C',  100);
 insert into testTable values('D',  0);
```

Query1:

```
 SELECT Column1,
        SUM(Column2) / COUNT(*) AS Column2
 FROM testTable where column2<>0
 GROUP BY Column1;
```

Output:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 200 |
| B | 250 |
| C | 100 |

Query2:

```
 SELECT Column1,
        Coalesce(SUM(Column2) / nullif(COUNT(CASE WHEN Column2 <> 0 THEN 1 END),0),0) AS Column2
 FROM testTable
 GROUP BY Column1;
```

Output:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 200 |
| B | 250 |
| C | 100 |
| D | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=290ceabcc285145f48d093b00975df74)*

Comment: `0 / 0` is not `0`, it's defined as `Not A Number` which you could represent as `NULL`. So I would remove the final `COALESCE`

Comment: You are absolutely right. I thought instead of NULL OP will prefer 0 in result.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for derived table to filter out the 0 column2 rows. Then, you can apply GROUP BY.

```sql
declare @table table (Column1 char(1),  Column2 int)
insert into @table values
('A',200),
('A',200),
('A',0  ),
('B',300),
('B',200),
('C',100);

SELECT Column1, (sum(column2) / count(column2) ) as column2
from
(
SELECT * FROM @TABLE where Column2 <> 0) as t
group by Column1
```

| Column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 200 |
| B | 250 |
| C | 100 |

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve distinct value of column1 and ignore zero value of column2 while division with total sum of column2. And also consider here divide by zero error.

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT t.column1
     , t.column2 / (CASE WHEN (t.total - t.total_zero) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE (t.total - t.total_zero) END)
FROM (SELECT column1
           , SUM(column2) column2
           , COUNT(CASE WHEN column2 = 0 THEN 1 END) total_zero
           , COUNT(1) total
      FROM test
      GROUP BY column1) t
```

Please check this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3853456941909ffffb8792415adc1f6f

Answer (score 0):

Use `AVG()` window function because you want the average value of `Column2`.

If you want all the values of `Column1` in the results even if they have only `0`s in `Column2`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1,
       AVG(CASE WHEN Column2 <> 0 THEN Column2 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1) Column2
FROM tablename;
```

If you want results for the values of `Column1` that have at least 1 `Column2` not `0`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Column1,
       AVG(Column2) OVER (PARTITION BY Column1) Column2
FROM tablename
WHERE Column2 <> 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cab91dd2035de715c79dea185981bb5e).

Note that SQL Server truncates the average of integers to an integer, so if you want the result as a floating point number you should multiply `Column2` by 1.0, like:

```
AVG(CASE WHEN Column2 <> 0 THEN 1.0 * Column2 END)
```

or:

```
AVG(1.0 * Column2)
```